# Is Athena a viable/sensible choice for infrequently searching *unstructured* JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm recording request and response headers and bodies for all traffic to our API and **from** our API to 3rd party services into S3 as into tiny objects.

I want to be able to query this data infrequently. For example (pseudo-code):

```
select $.cars[0].color from "objects" where object_path in (....);
```

Other info:

- Many "objects" in S3 won't have a valid path to `$.cars[0].color` (it's just one example).
- I hope to not use Glue.
- Cost is important - this is something that will be queried *very* infrequently. Configuring some ElasticSearch/similar solution is terribly out of budget for the use case.
- I hope to not define my own set of schemas (this is simply not feasible).

Athena says it can search unstructured JSON. I'm having trouble creating a proof-of-concept to show this is true.

Is Athena right fr me? Am I missing a better solution?

Comment: [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)? It has operator to recursively walk down any nested structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think Athena will work for your case.

- Athena handles missing properties in JSON objects. For example, if you define the `cars` column as `array<struct<color:string>>`:

  - the property can be missing ⇒ `SELECT cars …` will be `NULL`
  - it can be an empty list ⇒ `SELECT cars[1] …` (Athena arrays start at 1) will result in an error, but `element_at(cars, 1)` and `try(cars[1])` will return `NULL`
  - the object may be missing the `color` property ⇒ `SELECT cars[1].color …` will be `NULL`
  - for completely free-form JSON define the column as `string` and use [the JSON functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/json.html) to query it.
- Glue is not necessary. Create the table manually, from your application, or with CloudFormation, and configure it to use [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) and you will not have to think about using Glue crawlers at all.
- Athena doesn't cost anything when you don't use it, and if you will query only infrequently this is key. Make sure to compress your data, and partition it in a way that supports your query patterns (e.g. by date or month if you most often will query recent data).
- Not sure what you mean by having to define your "own set of schemas", so perhaps you can clarify that part?